# Replace some character using regex in python string

Tags: python, regex, string

i have a string:

```
 id:'somecharet',  status: 'running',
```

How using regex take all character from `:` and go left to . I need to receive `id` and `status` and then change received values to `"id"` and `"status"`

result needed:

```
 "id":'somecharet',  "status": 'running',
```

I used to find all keys, but how to replace it to new one?

```
find = re.compile(r' (\S*?):')
newstr = find.findall(new)
```

Of course i can use `replace` for all x30 keys i have but it isn't ok i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you even consider using regex for this? IMHO the `replace()` function is sufficient here.
Take this as an example:

```
str = "id:'somecharet',  status: 'running', "
print (str.replace('id', '"id"'))
```

Output:

```
"id":'somecharet',  status: 'running',
```

Comment: replace isn't ok i have 30 + different keys